# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCCodeModel unable to cast to VCCodeModel

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run the following code(to discover all variable names in a vc++ project):

```
                VCCodeModel model = _applicationObject.Solution.Item(1).CodeModel as VCCodeModel;


                foreach (VCCodeVariable elem in model.Variables)
                {
                    string s = elem.DisplayName;

                    // ...
                }
```

But it fails to work as the conversion does not succeed and returns null, and I'm running this code from a c++ project.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Lots of possibilities, including obscure stuff like the thread state.  Use a cast instead of *as* so you get a proper exception that tells you what the problem is.

Comment: I get exception: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCCodeModel.VCCodeModel'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{5A716328-5325-4A51-AEF4-EFBB8A10B89F}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: Two possible reasons.  Item(1) isn't actually a C++ project.  Or that thread state I mentioned, this code should run on an STA thread.  If this runs in a console mode project the put [STAThread] on the Main() method.